# How to know which process makes my disk active?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, noise

I have a main SSD disk and a secondary HDD disk. My OS is Windows 10.

A few weeks ago, I started to notice that something was "scratching" (specific noise) for long durations on the HDD disk, but there is nothing installed on it AND no data (maybe 1 or 2 videos).

How can I know what is the process using my secondary disk ? (I've already disabled indexing).

Also is there a way to shut this disk down using software ? (so far I've just unplugged it and the noise has completely gone).

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely
[Scheduled Defrag](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/30/how-to-disable-automatic-drive-optimization-in-windows-10/)

Otherwise, you can know in detail with [Resource Monitor](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/28/a-detailed-windows-resource-monitor-guide/)

And even the Windows 10 task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times Resource Monitor will do the trick. But if you nee a "more in depth" analyses you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Microsoft/Sysinternals. It gives you a few additional featured, e.g. filtering.

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft/Sysinternals will show you which files and folders are accessed.